# InstallShield: Detect Chrome Installed in a PRQ

Tags: google-chrome, installshield-2012

I'm using InstallShield 2012, and I included Chrome as a redistributable,  I'd like to detect if Chrome is installed.  The problem is that chrome.exe is installed to the user's appdata folder and the prerequisite condition dialog doesn't give me the option of selecting the AppDataFolder

thanks

Comment: I don't know how InstallShield works, but maybe you can check if HKLM\Software\Google\Chrome exists in Windows, though I don't know if that will be removed when Chrome is uninstalled.

Comment: The problem is that Chrome is installed either for the current user, or for all users.  If chrome is installed for all users, then you are correct, however if chrome is installed for the current user only, then I need to look in HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome.  The problem I'm having is that InstallShield prerequisites check all conditions not one or the other.